# Site Contents - Target Audience

Tags: sharepoint-online, audience-targeting, site-contents

Is there a way to set the target audience on `/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`?

Currently, I just set the target audience per list/library `view` settings. But if I can set the target audience on `/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx` then I don't have to set the target audience for individual views?

**EDIT**
For example, we have a Leave Request list that everyone has contribute permission. The default view is set to only display the current user's data. There are other views that contain other users' information that the current user don't need to see. I used target audiencing to `hide` the data from these other views. So I was just wondering if there's an easier way than setting up target audience on each view. User with contribute (or less) permission don't really need to see anything in the Site Contents. Everything they need to access are displayed in a webpart on a page.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unsupported to set the target audience on /_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx.

It is supported to target the following content to specific audiences:

Target list or library items to an audience

Target a Web Part to an audience

Target a navigation link to an audience

For more detailed information, refer to the following article：

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293

Answer (score 3):

Audiences are **not** a security feature. You can only hide information from users by using audiences. The data is still available to them via the default pages like view all site content or CSOM or via REST calls or even search.

Your question sounds like you try to use them as a permission tool. That's not what they are designed for. Their goal is to reduce the information overload for users by hiding information that is not relevant for them.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to do this when the permissions you set at the site level already takes care of this? I don't think there is any explicit way to set a target audience to this page.